# how to look for occurrence of a string, in out put of a command, in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a python script that does a test and prints pass or fail to the command line.
I want to run this script from a batch file continuously until it fails.
So I need to parse the output of the script from inside my batch file and either "goto start"
or continue to end of the batch file.

I did some research and it seems like I need to use the for /f command, but I dont know how to look for a string in the entire out put.

lets say my script is called test.py and I want to look for the string "PASS" in its output. What is the exact syntax to use the for /f command?

I am also open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the script to continue if the output of your python script is `PASS` then this should do the trick -

```
:loop
For /F %%a in ('test.py') do set output=%%a
if "%output%"=="PASS" goto :loop
```

If you don't add anything after the final if statement there it will just end the script, if you want you can just add `goto :EOF` (End Of File) after the if statement.

Comment: so "if "%output%"=="PASS"" will test to see if pass is in output, not equal to it?

Comment: if the output of your python script is 'PASS' the batch script will continue. If it is anything other than 'PASS' the batch script will end.

Comment: The solution I'm looking for is something that will look for "pass" in the whole line. so even if the put is "test 1 pass", it would evaluate to through. what is the conditional to test for a sub string?

Comment: Just realized what you were asking, sorry. If you want it to check if 'PASS' is in the string then Magoo's answer will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `FOR /F` at all.

```
@echo off
:loop
test.py|find /i "pass" >nul
if NOT errorlevel 1 goto loop
```

If python outputs any line containing `pass` (the `/i` makes it case-insensitive - `find "PASS"` would  be case-sensitive) then `errorlevel` is set to `0` otherwise, `errorlevel` is set `>0`.

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **OR GREATER THAN n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true, so you need `if not errorlevel 1` to test for `errorlevel 0`.

Comment: This is actually the best solution, but since this is a knowledge base, I chose the answer that solves it using the original intended way as the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

instead of doing it in batch, why not do it in your `test.py` ?

```
while true:
    ... do your stuff
    ... 
    if result == "FAIL"
        break
call some other commands ....
```

Comment: Because I'm not supposed to modify the python script.